# Microsoft Exchange Server Permission Insight

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2010, mailbox

I was just assigned management of our Exchange Servers. The person who installed and configured our Exchange 2010 Servers did not set up permissions correctly. I noticed that anyone within the organization can open a users mailbox without them being assigned. This is something the organization has NOT recognized as an issue but as a Network Administrator, is an major security issue.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

A entry level engineer can open another engineers mailbox if they wanted. Again, I did NOT set permissions this way.

I am currently reading about the Exchange 2010 Server in order to properly figure everything out. However I need a quick fix right now. How can I set permissions so someone like a Entry Level Engineer can not open another engineers mailbox?

Comment: ["setup" is not the same as "set up"](http://notaverb.com/setup).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please post the list of AD groups that this "Entry Level Engineer" belongs to.

In the Exchange Management Console, select a representative user and select "Manage Full Access Permission". It should look like this:

[image]

If there are other users or groups present in that dialog, that's where you'll need to begin to remove access.

> This is something the organization has NOT recognized as an issue but
>   as a Network Administrator, is an major security issue.

From a political perspective, though, don't come in *guns blazin'* to point out what the previous admin did incorrectly. There may have been a reason that this type of access was enabled. You'll look like a jackass for pursuing this without knowing the full context.

For example, I manage ~38 Exchange mail systems across a variety of clients. In some environments, non-technical principals or department heads request mailbox access to their users. I don't think *any* environment gives the presumption of email privacy on company systems. More advanced sites leverage journaling to accomplish the same. So get the full story before you make this a crusade...

Comment: I hate to see configurations like this myself, but very much *"get the full story before you make this a crusade."* It's worth noting that a normal install doesn't default to this, so this has to be a conscious change post-install, not someone ticking the wrong box in a setup wizard.

Comment: The full story is the guy had no I.T background and is a Civil Engineer. He really did not know what he was doing, but the mail server did work. Again we are a small company, who finally decided to hire a I.T Admin(me who was a Network Admin), but one of the few things I have no experience is to set up a Exchange Server. I'll just read and learn. To be honest the above did not help me. I'm sure you are right about your answer(thus the vote up), however like I said things are pretty "messed up". I'm going to make two test mailboxes and go from their. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, do you have any Active Directory experience? Some of the same security rules apply. Take an entry level user and look at the groups they belong to. Cross-reference them with the dialog posted in my answer.

Comment: Yes I do, with the Active Directory. Ya I think Im figuring it out. Thanks

Comment: Figure it out due to your answer. The security principal I removed was different, but thanks!